# Why does CSS rotate stutters when i have a background process? IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a simple CSS code that rotates an image when it is clicked, As shown bellow. This is standard spinner code that i toggle when its clicked.:

CSS:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spinner;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spinner;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner
{
    from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner
{
    from{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spinner
{
    from{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
    }
}
@keyframes spinner {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}
```

The CSS works just fine and smoothly up until it reaches this part of my JS code. Does IE or FF have a hard time doing 2 things at once? I dont get why it works just fine on Chrome:

JS:

```
var datas = _.map(sourceData, function (item, index) {
                return new sourceItem(item,index);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Animations and loops always pull up a lot of resources. try executing them one by one.

Delay the execution using

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // code here
},100); // milliseconds
```

Comment: this works but i'm sacrificing performance over appearance. T_T , But a fix is a fix. Thank you! Sad apart about it is i cant do the animation while doing the process. I guess its a limitation.